# Median Filter for ios

Tags: ios, uiimage, median

I'm looking to apply Median Filter to a UIImage in my iOS application.
Due to my company restrictions, i cannot use openGL filters.

Any ideas or current implementations would be very welcomed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple's [`Core Image`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185) framework may be your solution. To be precise, you need a subclass of [`CIFilter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which implements a median filter. (Guess you would be interested in `CIMedianFilter` or have a look at the [filter reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIMedianFilter))

```
CIIImage *inputImage = //...

CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIMedianFilter"];
[filter setDefaults];
[filter setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];

CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
```

To convert the `CIImage` to `UIImage` and vice versa:

```
CIImage *ciImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"].CIImage;
UIImage *uiImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:ciImage];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. seems like it should work - but the line "CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIMedianFilter"];" returns nil for some reason. any ideas why?

Comment: Sorry, don't have any idea. Did you tried other filter names?

Comment: I'm guessing it's just not available in iOS. I know some of the CI filters aren't there. That's why (I think) they have a function that queries the device for available filters.

Comment: CIMedianFilter still is not available, even on iOS 8.

Comment: iOS 9 is another story.  Core Image is now unified across OS X and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the github project:

https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

These are a lot of CIFilter-type filters that are GPU accelerated.

Another alternate: Use a Convolution Filter and roll your own median filter using CI's kernel language.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who can use OpenGL ES in your iOS app, this is how you calculate the median in a pixel neighborhood radius of your choosing:

```
kernel vec4 medianUnsharpKernel(sampler u) {
vec4 pixel = unpremultiply(sample(u, samplerCoord(u)));
vec2 xy = destCoord();
int radius = 3;
int bounds = (radius - 1) / 2;
vec4 sum  = vec4(0.0);
for (int i = (0 - bounds); i <= bounds; i++)
{
    for (int j = (0 - bounds); j <= bounds; j++ )
    {
        sum += unpremultiply(sample(u, samplerTransform(u, vec2(xy + vec2(i, j)))));
    }
}
vec4 mean = vec4(sum / vec4(pow(float(radius), 2.0)));
float mean_avg = float(mean);
float comp_avg = 0.0;
vec4 comp  = vec4(0.0);
vec4 median  = mean;
for (int i = (0 - bounds); i <= bounds; i++)
{
    for (int j = (0 - bounds); j <= bounds; j++ )
    {
        comp = unpremultiply(sample(u, samplerTransform(u, vec2(xy + vec2(i, j)))));
        comp_avg = float(comp);
        median = (comp_avg < mean_avg) ? max(median, comp) : median;
    }
}

return premultiply(vec4(vec3(abs(pixel.rgb - median.rgb)), 1.0)); 
}
```

A brief description of the steps
1. Calculate the mean of the values of the pixels surrounding the source pixel in a 3x3 neighborhood;
2. Find the maximum pixel value of all pixels in the same neighborhood that are less than the mean.
3. [OPTIONAL] Subtract the median pixel value from the source pixel value for edge detection.

If you're using the median value for edge detection, there are a couple of ways to modify the above code for better results, namely, hybrid median filtering and truncated media filtering (a substitute and a better 'mode' filtering). If you're interested, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

If someone would like to do it in Xamarin (for iOS), here is the code:

```
public static UIImage MedianFilter(UIImage image)
    {
        CIImage ciImage = new CIImage(image);

        var medianFilter = new CIMedianFilter() { Image = ciImage };
        CIImage output = medianFilter.OutputImage;
        var context = CIContext.FromOptions(null);
        var cgimage = context.CreateCGImage(output, output.Extent);
        var uiImage = UIImage.FromImage(cgimage);

        return uiImage;
    }
```